# MySQL des_decrypt cannot decrypt the string encripted by Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I use `des` to encrypt string, but I want to decrypt it using MySQL.

The Python package is pycrypto: https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
import binascii
des_cipher = DES.new(u'password')
print(binascii.hexlify(des_cipher.encrypt(u'11111111')))
print(des_cipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(u'dd3573a56ba157f8')))
>>> dd3573a56ba157f8
>>> 11111111
```

I tried the following queries. But neither worked.

```
SELECT des_decrypt(unhex('dd3573a56ba157f8'), 'password');
SELECT cast(des_decrypt(unhex('dd3573a56ba157f8'), 'password') AS VARCHAR(1000));
```

The output is `�5s�k�W�`,not `11111111` which I desire.

Comment: Use `HEX(DES_ENCRYPT())` to compare the difference in what MySQL creates and python creates, and perhaps you'll find a hint.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The value is `FFB21D993EF533F9771C3ECC9723E965C0`. Very strange...

Comment: Python isn't my specialty, so I'm really guessing... but I think you may need to use [`3DES`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.DES3-module.html) instead of `DES`.  MySQL's DES implementation appears to be Triple DES.